# Как удалить css

Tags: html, css

Как удалить css у одного объекта, если выставлены глобальные настройки в .css

```
    img {}
```

Мне нужно вставить изображение у которого не будет вообще никаких стилей.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Comment: задать новый класс для этого изображения и прописать новые стили

Comment: @soledar10 но серавно нужно задавать все стили, которые есть в первоначале, чтобы они не мешали вёрстке.

Comment: @entithat исходя из вопроса необходимо обнулить стили только для одного изображения. как определить для какого изображения необходимо сделать обнуление стилей, используя только css?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

all - Универсальное свойство, которое сбрасывает все значения свойств в исходные или наследуемые, за исключением свойств direction и unicode-bidi.

Значения

- initial Изменить все свойства, применяемые к элементу, на исходные
  значения.
- inherit Изменить все свойства, применяемые к элементу, на
  значения, наследуемые у родителя.
- unset Если свойство наследуется, то    его значение принимается как
  inherit, в противном случае оно    принимается как initial.

Можно прописать так.

```
<img style="all: unset;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Дай этому `img` какой-нибудь `id` в `html` коде. Потом обратись к этому `id` в `css` и пропиши `all: unset;`

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то:

- img имеет определенные свойства по умолчанию;
- img у определенного  блока не должен наследовать свойства по
  умолчанию.

Можно сделать так:

```
img { //какие-либо свойства занаддные глобально
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px;
}

.block img { //сброс унаследованных глобальных свойств
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Иногда требуется !important